# Iterate through all branches

Tags: java, git, github, branch, jgit

I want to get all commits of a specific branch with JGit.
Let's take for example [test-kitchen](https://github.com/test-kitchen/test-kitchen). It has 5 branches:

- master
- spec-coverage
- legacy-0.7
- sethvargo/docs
- sethvargo/full_chef_path

How can I iterate for example through `spec-coverage` only?

In this example I would get all available branches and commits. But I need to choose which branch I want the commits from.

**Extract:**

```
// branch
for (Ref branch : git.branchList().setListMode(ListMode.REMOTE).call()){
    git.checkout().setName(branch.getName()).call();
    System.out.println("Branch: " + branch.getName());

    // commits
    Iterable<RevCommit> commits = git.log().all().call();
    for (RevCommit commit : commits) {
        System.out.println(commit);
        // doing something with the commits...
    }
}
```

Comment: Define "iterate"?  Walk the commit history backwards? How far?

Comment: For example getting all commits of a specific branch.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description you are trying to do the equivalent of "git log ", the [jgit-cookbook](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/porcelain/ShowLog.java) has a snippet that shows how to iterate over all commits like you do, but in this case you can select to list all commits of the branch by using add() and not all() to iterator only over commits on the branch:

```
    Iterable<RevCommit> logs = new Git(repository).log()
            .add(repository.resolve("remotes/origin/checkoutbranch"))
            .call();
    for (RevCommit rev : logs) {
        ...
    }
```

I have now also updated the jgit-cookbook snippet to show the difference of using all() on log().

Comment: When I replace `checkoutbranch` with for example `spec-coverage`, I get `Caught Exception: Ref spec-coverage can not be resolved`.  
I'm working on a remote branch. Do I have to set additional parameters?

Comment: for remote branches you probably need to make them available locally first, as far as I see the remote commands in jgit are not powerful enough here... not sure how commandline git would allow to do that even?

Comment: What about `setListMode(ListMode.REMOTE)` or something like that?

Comment: The ListMode is only used for branchList()/ListBranchCommand, not for commit-logs and it only affects which local branches are included or not. If you have the remote-branch, but did not yet create a matching local branch, you might be able to use something like "remotes/origin/spec-coverage", where "origin" is the name of the remote repository.

Comment: Just to amend the above said, it is not necessary to checkout the branch first. Irrespective of the current branch, you can show the log starting with a certain commit like this:
    `new Git( repository ).log().add( commit-id ).call();`
To resolve a commit-id, you can use repository.resolve( name-of-branch )